# Q: Tooltwist 8.3 deployment navpoints not generating properly

Tags: tooltwist

I'm using Tooltwist as a platform in developing our web projects, and as part of using of ToolTwist we use a commandline deployment to our server.

Here is my problem, if we run the command 'tooltwist -i deploy' to deploy the project on our Dev server it will prompt a message saying 
BUILD SUCCESS  Done, without errors.

But after starting our server and browse our web site we always see a distorted pages. And I as check the tooltwist log file this what I found.

2015-04-27 18:34:00,419 WARN  t.w.WbdGenerator - Unknown website asset stylesheet/myrp.products.transaction_report_style.css used by myrp.products.transaction_z_report_styles@2:com.myrp.widgets.ConditionalStyleSheetWidget
2015-04-27 18:34:00,420 WARN  t.w.WbdGenerator - Unknown website asset stylesheet/myrp.products.transaction_report_style.css used by myrp.products.transaction_z_report_styles@2:com.myrp.widgets.ConditionalStyleSheetWidget
2015-04-27 18:34:00,420 WARN  t.w.WbdGenerator - Unknown website asset stylesheet/myrp.products.transaction_report_style.css used by myrp.products.transaction_z_report_styles@2:com.myrp.widgets.ConditionalStyleSheetWidget
2015-04-27 18:34:00,424 WARN  t.w.WbdGenerator - Unknown website asset stylesheet/myrp.zones.global.css used by myrp.pages.hub_p_adminLogin@14:com.myrp.widgets.ConditionalStyleSheetWidget
2015-04-27 18:34:00,424 WARN  t.w.WbdGenerator - Unknown website asset stylesheet/myrp.zones.hub_global.css used by myrp.pages.hub_p_adminLogin@13:com.myrp.widgets.ConditionalStyleSheetWidget
2015-04-27 18:34:00,425 WARN  t.w.WbdGenerator - Unknown website asset stylesheet/myrp.products.transaction_report_style.css used by myrp.products.transaction_z_report_styles@2:com.myrp.widgets.ConditionalStyleSheetWidget
2015-04-27 18:34:00,425 WARN  t.w.WbdGenerator - Unknown website asset stylesheet/myrp.products.transaction_report_style.css used by myrp.products.transaction_z_report_styles@2:com.myrp.widgets.ConditionalStyleSheetWidget
2015-04-27 18:34:00,425 WARN  t.w.WbdGenerator - Unknown website asset stylesheet/myrp.products.transaction_report_style.css used by myrp.products.transaction_z_report_styles@2:com.myrp.widgets.ConditionalStyleSheetWidget
2015-04-27 18:34:00,426 WARN  t.w.WbdGenerator - Unknown website asset stylesheet/myrp.products.transaction_report_style.css used by myrp.products.transaction_z_report_styles@2:com.myrp.widgets.ConditionalStyleSheetWidget

Any thought on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on your log file, I think you have missed those css files and tooltwist can't find those while generating the navpoints and that brings to have a distorted pages.

Possible solution that would help is: if you were able to find those css in your ttsvr project '/ttsvr/generated/stylesheet' folder, try to copy them and paste on your project folder 'PROJECT_NAME/WebContent/stylesheet' and then commit them and also if you are using the artifactory you need to publish your changes to artifactory by using the command 'gradle aP' and try to run the deployment command again.

I hope this can help you.. Thanks

Comment: Hi Cris it is generating properly now. Thanks :)